# HTML5/javascript streaming of an already playing list of videos

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming

I am currently trying to set up a sort of video stream using HTML5. The goal is this: I need to create a television-like interface wherein the user, once they click on the link to the stream, will see the already in progress video.

Right now, I have set things up to a point where I can play a playlist of videos in a row, but I can't figure out how to set it up so that it will already be playing when the user accesses it. basically, I want it to perpetually play regardless of user input.

I originally tried using streaming software, but made little to no progress. Also, considering that the long term goal is to run approximately 60 channels at one time, having the overhead of running software like that would be bad.

The filetype of the videos is .mp4.

I am currently using a javascript linked list to cycle through the videos. That is working great, I just need it to not have to be started every time.

Thank you for any help. The implementation of this has been driving me crazy for about two weeks now, and I'm at a pretty hard dead end at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to play all of them, instead:

1. keep track of when those videos should have started (e.g. video 1 starts at 8pm EST)
2. When they click to go to a channel, start that video playing at the elapsed time

For example, if video 1 starts at 8pm EST and it's now 8:17pm EST, when they click for that video, it would start playing it at 17 minutes into the video. This will simulate that the channels/videos have been playing all along.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that. So it would run based on time instead of perpetually. Each user would have the video start based on a running time variable.

Thank you very much, that will work much much better than what I was trying.